# Slow Speeds over Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, wireless-router

I have cable Internet that averages about 35 MB/sec down and 7MB/sec up, but been having intermittent Wi-Fi problems for several months now. I’ve changed my router a couple times to no avail. I’m currently use a [TP-Link Archer C9 (AC1900 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router)](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C9.html).

Seemingly randomly, the connection over the Wi-Fi seems to get incredibly slow. Down to less than .25 MB/sec down and .05 MB/sec up. (I use speedtest.net to measure the speed.) Following some advice on here I’ve attempted changing the Wi-Fi channel and channel width and this seems to fix the problem for a short time before reverting back to being slow.

This isn’t just an Internet connection that’s slowing down. Accessing the router admin panel or transferring files over Wi-Fi is incredibly slow, as well. I don’t live in a very congested area, with only a couple other networks showing up, even hidden networks. I do have many devices on my network, 4 phones, 2 tablets, 2 laptops, an Xbox 360, an Xbox One and 1 desktop (plus 1 wired desktop), but only a few of them are ever being used at once.

- All the laptops and desktops are running Windows 10.
- The phones are all Android including a Moto E and an HTC Desire.
- The tablets are Kindle Fire HDs.
- The wireless desktop is a Dell XPS Special Edition with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 card.

I’m at a loss of what to try next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Added some details.

Comment: Can you explicilty state that the *wired* desktop internet connection does not slow down when the wireless connections do?

Comment: It does not. It's always fast and never had an issue with it.

Comment: Do you have a proper placement for the Wi-Fi antenna, and is it positioned correctly for the placement?

Comment: My house isn't that large for distance to really be an issue. The wifi router is just down the hall from the wireless desktop. All the devices receive a strong wifi signal.

Comment: Does the speed revert to normal at any time? For example after a washing machine stops running - could it be faulty wiring somewhere causing a lot of electrical interference (you could wander around with a portable AM radio to find out)?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 Can you clarify what units you mean when you say "MB"? Is that MebiBytes (1,048,576's of 8-bit bytes) or megabits (1,000,000's of 1-bit bits) or something else?

Comment: It's Megabytes.  The wifi does speed up at times, but there's no regularity to it.  Is there anyway to track the bandwidth usage of all devices on a network?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the 2.4Ghz and testing completely on 5Ghz?